# Start a Google Hangouts by passing email as parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, email, web-applications, google-hangouts

I'm trying to start a new Google hangout inside an web application. The facts is that I'm only succeeding by opening a new tab or windows. 
I'd like to directly start a hangout by passing any email adress as parameter.

As anyone an idea?

Thank you already.

Cedric.

Comment: Sort of, except that I'm looking for every ways to start a hangout. If it's not by passing parameters inside the URI, every way would be good for me.
TY for answering by the way.

Comment: Correct, it isn't possible as of today.  However, it is something they are looking into.